# Do guards re-stock on arrows?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've been pickpocketing city guards for steel arrows for awhile now, as they seem to be a pretty good source of basic ammo, but I'm a bit worried about exhausting my suppliers.

Do guards refill their arrow supply every so often, or are they just disposable arrow dispensers?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Pick pocket the arrows from the NPC's who are shooting at targets. You have to do it before or after they are actually shooting at the targets unless you have the steal equipped perk unlocked. Then replace the ones you took with 1 arrow of the type of arrow you want to have a lot of. Then when they shoot the target you collect the arrows that hit the target and it will always be the arrow you gave them. NPC's get unlimited arrows to shoot so long as one arrow is on them they will continue to shoot that arrow.

My example was i joined the thieves guild and pick pocketed everyone in there and gave them all 1 deadra arrow. Now i go from the main room to the training room and collect all the deadra arrows they shoot at the targets to refill. I can get a stack of 100 or so arrows in about 7-10 min of running back and forth. GL to ya.

Comment: Excellent idea. Welcome to the site!

Comment: That is outstanding.

Comment: I have no words for how awesome that is.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me. Everyone still shoots steel arrows. I've tried it in several different areas where NPCs shoot arrows. Any suggestions?

Comment: You have to steal the arrows either before or after they are shooting. Basically you need to steal them while they sleep or right when they wake up. Once they equip the arrows you wont see them unless you have the perk to steal equipped items. So if they are shooting at a target its already to late and they have equipped the arrows.

Comment: Awesome tip. It works with Lydia too! So I assume with all followers. She is firing Glass arrows now. The Glass arrows quiver shows up on her, and once in a while I find glass arrows in Skeevers and other prey that she attacked. Just give her one arrow of the type you want her to use.